# wp-mail-smtp in wordpress Connection refused (111)

Tags: wordpress

I developed my site with WordPress 4.5.3.I installed plugin WP-Mail-SMTP.I create mail account with my host tigrimigri.com.
with this setting

```
Secure SSL/TLS Settings
Username: Your Email Address
Incoming Server: freehost.tigrimigri.com
IMAP Port: 993
POP3 Port: 995

Outgoing Server: freehost.tigrimigri.com
SMTP Port: 25
```

Then I write this info at plugin WP-Mail-SMTP setting 
But when I test email I get this error

```
The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
2016-07-02 12:21:04 Connection: opening to ssl://freehost.tigrimigri.com:25, timeout=300, options=array (
                                      )
2016-07-02 12:21:04 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
2016-07-02 12:21:04 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not sent mail through freehost.tigrimigri.com

Check the faq section on the site:

http://tigrimigri.com/faq.html

Can I use e-mail?

Sorry it is not possible yet to sent / receive e-mail through our server.

Comment: Please if you know free host support laravel5.2 and email messaging tell me